# Taylor series of $1/(e^x-a)$ about 0?

Tags: taylor-expansion, closed-form

I know what the Taylor series for $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ about 0 is, and it's a function of Bernoulli numbers.

However, $\frac{1}{e^x-a}$ seems to be much more convoluted. Does anybody know the general term of this series?

If it exists, finding it on Google is challenging, due to the mathematical notation.

Comment: If you have trouble Googling it, consider using a calculator. I used Symbolab and found Maclaurin series of $\dfrac{1}{e^x-a}$ as:$$\dfrac{1}{1-a}-\dfrac{1}{1-a^2}x+\dfrac{a+1}{2(1-a)^3}x^2-+\cdots$$

Comment: @ParasKhosla What is general term? I can easily produce the series with Mathematica, but I need to know the general term, not just the first few terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, maybe the Binomial Theorem is needed.
See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem.
Actually, we can obtain that
\begin{align}
(e^x-a)^{-1} &= -a^{-1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^x}{a}\right)^k\\
&=-\frac{1}{a} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^k} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(kx)^n}{n!}\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{a^{k+1}} \right)x^n.
\end{align}

Well, since
$$ \frac{1}{1-y}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} y^k,$$
we have that
$$ y \left(\frac{1}{1-y}\right)'= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k y^k.$$
Let $c_0(y)=\frac{1}{1-y}$,
and for $n\geq 1$, let
$$c_n(y)=y\cdot c_{n-1}(y)'.$$
Then  we have
$$-\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{a^k} =-\frac{1}{a}c_n\left(\frac{1}{a}\right).$$

The first five terms are
$$ \frac{1}{1-a},-\frac{1}{(a-1)^2},-\frac{a+1}{(a-1)^3},-\frac{a (a+4)+1}{(a-1)^4},-\frac{(a+1) (a (a+10)+1)}{(a-1)^5},-\frac{a (a (a (a+26)+66)+26)+1}{(a-1)^6}.$$

Comment: That is not it yet because the second sum is infinite, and I want it to be a closed-form, right?

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @Aaron Jia's answer
$$\frac{1}{e^x-a}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{a^{k+1}} \right)x^n$$ let
$$c_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{a^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{a}\,\Phi \left(\frac{1}{a},-n,0\right) $$ where appears the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.

So,

$$\frac{1}{e^x-a}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} -\frac{\Phi \left(\frac{1}{a},-n,0\right)}{a\, n!} x^n$$ and the coefficients are then
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & \frac{1}{1-a} \\
 1 & -\frac{1}{(a-1)^2} \\
 2 & \frac{-a-1}{2 (a-1)^3} \\
 3 & \frac{-a^2-4 a-1}{6 (a-1)^4} \\
 4 & \frac{-a^3-11 a^2-11 a-1}{24 (a-1)^5} \\
 5 & \frac{-a^4-26 a^3-66 a^2-26 a-1}{120 (a-1)^6} 
\end{array}
\right)$$ to be compared to the expansion
$$\frac{1}{1-a}-\frac{x}{(a-1)^2}+\frac{(-a-1) x^2}{2 (a-1)^3}+\frac{\left(-a^2-4
   a-1\right) x^3}{6 (a-1)^4}+\frac{\left(-a^3-11 a^2-11 a-1\right) x^4}{24
   (a-1)^5}+\frac{\left(-a^4-26 a^3-66 a^2-26 a-1\right) x^5}{120
   (a-1)^6}+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Comment: The first term, n=0, is 0, so the above needs a little correction.

Comment: @JRS. I do not agree : it is not $0$ so it does not need any little correction. Cheers.